# Not able to draw Doughnut Chart from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to draw Doughnut Chart using [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart)
I am getting proper json  response from my localhost 
my code is :

```js
    
    
        $(document).on('click', '#plotGraph', function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            alert("hello");
                            $.getJSON("PlotExpenseGraph", function(data1) {
                                alert("hiiiii");
                                console.log(data1);
                                console.log(data1.expenseList[0].param);
                                var pieData;
                                $.each(data1.expenseList, function(position, expenseList) {
                                    console.log(expenseList.param);
                                    console.log(expenseList.totalCount);
                                    console.log(expenseList.totalValue);
                                    pieData = {
                                        value: expenseList.totalValue,
                                        color: "#F7464A",
                                        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                                        label: expenseList.param
                                    }
                                });
                                var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
                                var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
                                new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(pieData);
                            });
                        });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="plotGraph">Plot graph</a>
      <canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

My console data is

param: "Advertising"

totalCount: 2

totalValue: 754

Advertising

Advertising

2

754

My code is not plotting any figure and also it is not giving any error on console.
What scanges should I make to work above code properly.

Comment: It seems wrong to overwrite `pieData` in each loop over and over again. Probably you should add to some array instead.

Comment: Not getting how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChartJS expects an array of objects as parameter to the `Doughnut()` method. You on the other hand just create the objects and thereby overwrite the last object.

Instead you should declare `pieData` to be an array and add entries inside the `each()` callback like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#plotGraph', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.getJSON("PlotExpenseGraph", function (data1) {

    // prepare parameter to ChartJS
    var pieData = [];
    $.each(data1.expenseList, function (position, expenseList) {

      // add respective entry
      pieData.push({
        value : expenseList.totalValue,
        color : "#F7464A",
        highlight : "#FF5A5E",
        label : expenseList.param
      });

    });

    // paint
    var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
    new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(pieData);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks It is working. I would like to ask  how to different color for each label and apart from `label : expenseList.param` how can I show extra parameter here like `totalCount` value.

Comment: In the inner loop you assign all the values for the pie chart. If you want different colors, you can assign them there, as well as another label.